# "cannot find symbol" and "package javax.media.opengl does not exist" during Scilab compilation

Tags: javac, scilab, powerpc

I am trying to compile Scilab on a RHEL-ppc64 platform. I want to use CLI only. The ./configure script went well, but the **make** is giving me headaches because I don't know where to look for a solution.

Here that is (a sample as it's very long):

This is the part going well:

```
    Making all in modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules'
Making all in prebuildjava
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/prebuildjava'
Buildfile: /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/prebuildjava/build.xml

scirenderer:
     [echo] Using:
     [echo] ${thirdparty.dir}
     [echo]
     [echo]
     [echo]

init:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 117 source files to /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/build/classes
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/Canvas.java
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/Drawer.java
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/DrawingTools.java
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/PackageInfo.java
```

This is when things start to get nasty:

```
   [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/utils/shapes/geometry/CubeFactory.java
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/utils/shapes/geometry/SphereFactory.java
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/utils/shapes/geometry/TetrahedronFactory.java
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/implementation/jogl/JoGLCanvas.java:22: error: package com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt does not exist
    [javac] import com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.ImageUtil;
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/implementation/jogl/JoGLCanvas.java:23: error: package com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt does not exist
    [javac] import com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.Screenshot;
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/implementation/jogl/JoGLCanvas.java:28: error: package javax.media.opengl does not exist
    [javac] import javax.media.opengl.DebugGL2;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/implementation/jogl/JoGLCanvas.java:29: error: package javax.media.opengl does not exist
    [javac] import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/implementation/jogl/JoGLCanvas.java:30: error: package javax.media.opengl does not exist
    [javac] import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
    [javac]                          ^
```

And that's the end:

```
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/implementation/jogl/JoGLCanvas.java:302: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             GL2 gl = getGl().getGL2();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class GL2
    [javac]   location: class JoGLCanvas
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/ruler/graduations/TinyIntervalFormat.java:24: warning: [serial] serializable class TinyIntervalFormat has no definition of serialVersionUID
    [javac] public class TinyIntervalFormat extends DecimalFormat {
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] /root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/src/org/scilab/forge/scirenderer/ruler/graduations/UserDefinedFormat.java:26: warning: [serial] serializable class UserDefinedFormat has no definition of serialVersionUID
    [javac] public class UserDefinedFormat extends DecimalFormat {
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] 100 errors
    [javac] 3 warnings

BUILD FAILED
/root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/prebuildjava/build.xml:34: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/scirenderer/build.xml:116: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 10 seconds
make[2]: *** [java] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules/prebuildjava'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/scilab/scilab-5.5.1/modules'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I have seen around people saying that the "source" issue has to do with different versions of javac being used, but I can't modify the javac options as they are coming from the script. Also, I don't know why I am missing those modules, and what they for...

Any ideas how I should proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Had a tough time building Scilab as well, it seems it doesn't work with the lsstest version of jogl.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624771/how-can-i-make-my-ubuntu-look-for-a-library-from-a-given-source