# How can I make my Ubuntu look for a library from a given source

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation

I'm trying to compile scilab (yes, my task is to compile it instead of using apt-get) but after solving some problems I get the following one:

```
checking minimal version (Specification-Version 2.2) of jogl2... configure: error: Wrong version of jogl2. Expected at least 2.2. Found 2.1
```

2.1 seems to be the latest one apt-get offers so I downloaded the newest version from http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/jogamp-all-platforms.7z and successfully compiled it (sudo ant junit.run returns successful unit tests) but when I go back to scilab it still finds the 2.1 version of jogl. How can I make it look for the newer one I compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem with Scilab, I'm trying to build it from https://github.com/opencollab/scilab/blob/master .

The problem is that the file scilab/configure looks for jars named "**jogl2***", however the newest version of jogl no longer uses that jar name.

<s>So ultimately Scilab won't build with jogl 2.2, yet the configure file ironically requires it.</s>  I'll keep you posted if I find a workaround.

EDIT:
Scilab does build with jogl 2.2, just not with jogl 2.3 which is the latest version we both tried. Jogl 2.3 restructures package names.

If you get jogl 2.2.4 http://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.2.4/jar/  install the jars in **/usr/share/java**.  To answer your original question,  Java on Ubuntu will look there first.

However you still need to do one hack to get scilabs configure script to work. Rename **/usr/share/java/jogl-all.jar** to **/usr/share/java/jogl2.jar** .

gouessej 's Comment is correct it, someone will likely modify Scilab to work with the latest jogl. When they do, they may want to tackle the package management logic buried in the configure script, and move it to something like Maven.

Comment: Maybe you should modify Scilab to work with the latest version of JOGL, it's not very difficult. Moreover, we (JogAmp) have never named our JOGL JAR "jogl2", this is the name given by the package maintainers of some Linux distros.

Comment: Well then, how do I make it work with the latest version of JOGL? The newest compiled version of JOGL does not provide jars the scilab configure script is looking for.

Comment: I've found that the build does work with version 2.2.4 of jogl,along with a manual rename of the jar file.  Updated the answer above.

Comment: You can make it work with JOGL 2.3.1, some packages have been moved: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=682

Comment: Now the compiler throws other errors but at least the installation moved forward, thanks!